# Openig a Fragment from PageAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I follow this tutorial to create a viewpager gallery http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/.
I added a onClick listener to the ImageView in the PagerAdapter. 
I want to open a fragment when the imageview is clicked. How can I do that?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.replace(R.id.frameContent, new TravelogueFragment()).commit(); 
    }
```

I alreary tried that code inside my class which extend PagerAdapter but Im getting an error with the getFragmentManager() it says that getFragmentManager is undefine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use interface and listener. You can see [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18612049/1088643). In my case, I replace `Fragment` when list item click, so you'll only need to adapt it and it will work.