# Press back button current fragment persist not restore previous fragment

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-event

I have Fragment Activity which contains a Framelayout for fragment transition. A fragment named `LeadActiviy` extends `SherlockListFragment` contains `Asynctask`, in `AsyncTask`'s method  `onPostExcute` contents `else` block statement. In `else` block current fragment replaced by `ItemNotFound` extends Fragment. After set the contents of `ItemNotFound` in framelayout when press back button it's current state persist  & not appear its previous fragment. Please help me to solve issue-

Code of AsyncTask's method onPostExecute from LeadActivity ...

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
    pDialog.dismiss();
    //FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
    //final FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(success==1){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), leadlist,R.layout.leadlistview, new String[] { Tag_Lead},
                    new int[] { R.id.textView6});
            // updating listview
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            //get leads of order
            ListView lv=getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String pid=((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView6)).getText().toString();

                    LeadDetail frag=new LeadDetail();
                    Bundle bnd=new Bundle();
                    bnd.putString("lead",pid);
                    frag.setArguments(bnd);
                    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }

            });
            }
            else {
                String e="Lead Not Found";              
                ItemNotFound frag=new ItemNotFound();
                //Frag1 frag=new Frag1();
                Bundle bnd=new Bundle();
                bnd.putString("data",e);
                frag.setArguments(bnd);
                FragmentManager fm1=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft1=fm1.beginTransaction();
                ft1.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag,st);
                ft1.addToBackStack(st);
                ft1.commit();
               }
        }
```

Code for ItemNotFound.............

```
  public class ItemNotFound extends SherlockFragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemnotfound, container, false);
    TextView tv=(TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    Bundle bnd=this.getArguments();
    String s=bnd.getString("data");
    tv.setText(s);
    return V;
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18612049/1088643).

I have a `ViewPager` with three pages which contains `Fragments`. In first page, I have a `ListFragment` and `onListItemClick` I replace that `Fragment` with another one. When `Back Button` is pressed, I go back to `ListFragment`.