# Is Using a 'Root' Fragment A Better Way Replace Fragments in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Replacing Fragments in ViewPager is a question that has been asked many times but most answers are hacks, broken/not complete or quite old. This example is working really well - https://github.com/danilao/fragments-viewpager-example but it actually uses an empty root fragment and adds the real fragment on createView.

Is there any other better way to avoid having to use a root frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach would be to override your `PagerAdapter`'s [getItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getItemPosition(java.lang.Object)) to update your PagerAdapter with the new Fragment:

> Called when the host view is attempting to determine if an item's position has changed. Returns [POSITION_UNCHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#POSITION_UNCHANGED) if the position of the given item has not changed or [POSITION_NONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#POSITION_NONE) if the item is no longer present in the adapter.
>
> The default implementation assumes that items will never change position and always returns [POSITION_UNCHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#POSITION_UNCHANGED).

In this case, pages that haven't changed return `PagerAdapter.POSITION_UNCHANGED`, the Fragment that is removed returns `PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE`, and the new Fragment gets its new position.﻿

You'll change the underlying data in your `PagerAdapter`, then call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()). This is what triggers the `ViewPager` to call `getItemPosition()` for each visible `Fragment`, replacing or moving them as needed.

Comment: The small problem with this technique is that if you want to completely replace Fragment A with Fragment B in a `FragmentPagerAdapter` for example, Fragment A is simply detached but not destroyed, so it's still around even if you want to get rid of it. Do you have a workaround for this ?

Comment: @BladeCoder - switching over to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is certainly one way. Providing deep or persistent tabs is a [navigation anti-pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sww4omntVjs&feature=youtu.be&t=539) that should be avoided anyways.

Comment: Can't agree more about deep and persistent tabs, that's why I've always disliked the Instagram app. I developed an app where the user may choose in the options if he wants fragment A or fragment B to represent the content of a tab, and I opted for the child fragment option to allow switching the display on-the-fly. I believe that approach is acceptable in that case.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. For those looking for a complete example, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/18612049/206292

Answer (score 0):

Your example uses the right technique (child fragments inside root fragment) but the wrong way: for managing child fragments inside the root fragment, it must use the child fragment manager using `getChildFragmentManager()`.